# Problems of Conversion of a List of HashMaps from/to JSON fails with Moshi 1.8.0 using Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I looked at many examples but didn't help me solve my problem,
I have this model for mapping with JSON:

```
data class SomeResponse (
...
@Json(name = "dictionary")
var dictionary: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>? = null )
```

And I am using Moshi for converting to/from JSON, and when the conversion process starts an exception happen

> Platform java.util.HashMap> (with no annotations) requires
>   explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

and this is my Moshi object:

```
val customDateAdapter = object : Any() {
val dateFormat: DateFormat

init {
    dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH)
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
}

@ToJson
@Synchronized
fun dateToJson(d: Date): String {
    return dateFormat.format(d)
}

@FromJson
@Synchronized
fun dateToJson(s: String): Date {

    try {
        val date = dateFormat.parse(s)
        Timber.d("DATE_FORMATTER Did format: $date")
        return date
    } catch (e: ParseException) {

        try {
            val df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
            df.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")
            return df.parse(s)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return Date()
    }
}

private val stringArrayListAdapter = object : Any() {

    @ToJson
    @Synchronized
    fun arrayListToJson(list: ArrayList<String>) : List<String> = list

    @FromJson
    @Synchronized
    fun arrayListFromJson(list: List<String>) : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList(list)
}

val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .add(customDateAdapter)
    .add(stringArrayListAdapter)
    .build()
```

How to fix that problem

Answer (score 1):

Moshi only supports `Map`. Use `Map` or create an Adapter for the `HashMap` as well.